# How to write the current timestamp in a Perl file?

Tags: perl

How do I write the current timestamp in a Perl file?

I have made a file named `myperl.pl` which will print the current timestamp. The file is given below:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
@timeData = localtime(time);
print "@timeData\n";
```

Now I am trying to redirect the output of this file into another text file. The script is below:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
@myscript = "/usr/bin/myperl.pl";
@myfile = "/usr/bin/output_for_myperl.txt";
perl "myscript" > "myfile\n";
```

While running this I am getting below error:

> perl sample_perl_script.pl
>   String found where operator expected at sample_perl_script.pl line 4, near "perl "myscript""
>   (Do you need to predeclare perl?)
>   syntax error at sample_perl_script.pl line 4, near "perl "myscript""
>   Execution of sample_perl_script.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Answer (score 40):

Another tip.  If you want to control the format of the timestamp, I usually throw in a subroutine like the following.  This will return a scalar in the format of "20120928 08:35:12".

```
sub getLoggingTime {

    my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst)=localtime(time);
    my $nice_timestamp = sprintf ( "%04d%02d%02d %02d:%02d:%02d",
                                   $year+1900,$mon+1,$mday,$hour,$min,$sec);
    return $nice_timestamp;
}
```

Then change your code to:

```
my $timestamp = getLoggingTime();
```

Comment: this game me a date string of "19000100 00:00:25921516" when I tried it recently. Is this because this is an old answer and no longer applies?

Comment: @Brady: works as expected over here `20151012 22:13:39` (perl 5.18.2 on win32)

Answer (score 12):

You need a file-handle to write to a file:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $timestamp = localtime(time);

open my $fh, '>', '/tmp/file'
   or die "Can't create /tmp/file: $!\n";

print $fh $timestamp;

close $fh;
```

Some documentation: [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)

Another solution is a script without a filehandle, just a print, then on the command line:

```
./script.pl > new_date_file
```

Comment: Thanks for editing my mistake ;)
(wrong URL)
Leaning Perl : added by ikegami.

Comment: Also changed it to call `localtime` in scalar context (since the program was outputting something useless) and added an error check to the `open`.

Comment: "Leaning Perl" sounds like a rather crooked book.

Comment: thanks a ton for this..it worked..I have only added the newline in the printf line.